# Rotate through img's that are created with fetched data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a working solution for this, but it seems pretty messy to me and not the correct way to do this in Vue.

I need to fetch data from a backend about a "Vendor". The vendor has photos that should be displayed on the page. I want one photo shown at a time, then rotate through them every 5s by changing their opacity, using setInterval.

I have a 'ref' for the img's. However, I cannot use it in '.then' because `this.$refs` is not available in `created()`. In this case, the "refs" are not available in `mounted()` either due to the asynchronous fetch in `created()`.

I obviously cannot put setInterval in update, because it creates a new listener for every update (yes, I'm an idiot and actually tried that...).

Right now, I have `updated()` setting `this.photoCount` every time it updates. setInterval is added in `created()` and does nothing until `this.photoCount` is no longer null.

```
<template>
    <notification-banner
        v-show="banner.displayed"
        :type="banner.type"
        :message="banner.message"
    ></notification-banner>

    <div class="container">
        <svg class="settingsIcon" width="24px" height="24px" stroke-width="1.5" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" color="#000000">
            <path d="M12 15a3 3 0 100-6 3 3 0 000 6z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
            <path d="M19.622 10.395l-1.097-2.65L20 6l-2-2-1.735 1.483-2.707-1.113L12.935 2h-1.954l-.632 2.401-2.645 1.115L6 4 4 6l1.453 1.789-1.08 2.657L2 11v2l2.401.655L5.516 16.3 4 18l2 2 1.791-1.46 2.606 1.072L11 22h2l.604-2.387 2.651-1.098C16.697 18.831 18 20 18 20l2-2-1.484-1.75 1.098-2.652 2.386-.62V11l-2.378-.605z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
        </svg>

        <div class="sidebar">
            <h1>{{vendor.name}}</h1>

            <p>{{vendor.email}}</p>
            
            <div class="personalUrl">
                <p>market.com/{{vendor.url}}</p>

                <svg @click="copyUrl" width="24px" height="24px" stroke-width="1.5" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" color="#000000">
                    <path d="M19.4 20H9.6a.6.6 0 01-.6-.6V9.6a.6.6 0 01.6-.6h9.8a.6.6 0 01.6.6v9.8a.6.6 0 01-.6.6z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                    <path d="M15 9V4.6a.6.6 0 00-.6-.6H4.6a.6.6 0 00-.6.6v9.8a.6.6 0 00.6.6H9" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contents">
            <h1>{{vendor.name}}</h1>

            <div class="vendorPhotos">
                <div class="vendorPhoto" v-for="(photo, i) in vendor.photos" :key="i">
                    <img ref="vendorPhoto" :src="`http://localhost:8000${photo}`" alt="Vendor provided image" :class="i===displayedPhoto ? 'displayPhoto' : 'hidePhoto'"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p>{{vendor.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            vendor: {},
            banner: {
                displayed: false,
                type: "",
                message: ""
            },
            displayedPhoto: 0,
            photoCount: null
        }
    },

    created(){
        let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
        let headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
        if(token !== null) headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;

        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/vendor${document.location.pathname}`, {
            method: "get",
            headers: headers,
        })
            .then(r=>r.json())
            .then((vendor)=>{
                this.vendor = vendor;
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                console.error(err);
            });

        setInterval(()=>{
            if(this.photoCount !== null){
                if(this.displayedPhoto >= this.photoCount){
                    this.displayedPhoto = 0;
                }else{
                    this.displayedPhoto++;
                }
            }
        }, 5000);
    },

    updated(){
        this.photoCount = this.$refs.vendorPhoto.length;
    }
```

How could I do this in a better, more "vue-like" way? My solution, while working, seems like garbage.

Comment: sounds like a good use case for a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html).  watch `vendor` which will run a callback once it's populated by the fetch and start your setInterval there

Comment: Yep, that sounds right. Thanks. Getting used to the Vue way of doing things.

Comment: @tao You're right, that is a better place for it. I'll make sure to go there in the future. Thanks. Also, I notice that you cleared the setInterval in beforeUnmount. Is that because the interval will continue to run even if the component is unmounted?

Comment: Yep, whenever you set an interval in a component you should clear it `beforeUnmout`. I decided to post it as an answer, hoping it might help others looking for the same type of advice. I tried to specify the reasoning behind the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd change:

- There's no need to count `$refs`. The information is already available in `vendor.photos.length`
- `photoCount` should be `computed`. Making it separate state runs the risk of not being in sync with `vendor.photos.count`, which could lead to subtle bugs. In principle, derived state (e.g: `computed`, store `getters`) should always be derived state, rather than keeping the same information in two separate places in state.
- the `displayedPhoto` increment function could be simplified to:

```js
methods: {
  changePhoto() {
    this.displayedPhoto = (this.displayedPhoto + 1) % this.photoCount
  }
}
```

- fetching vendor should be a standalone method (e.g: `fetchVendor`). This allows re-fetching whenever the business logic requires it, it's no longer coupled to component lifecycle
- I moved fetching in `mounted`. `created` is supposed to only hold code that needs to run before the component was added to DOM. Which is not the case for fetching data.
  Fetching in `created` creates the false impression the component might get away with not having to deal with rendering before fetch returned. Which is never true, not even when the backend runs on the same machine.
  I'd rather fetch in `mounted` and handle "loading..." state adequately (e.g: a loading indicator, a funny picture, etc...)
- I'd like to draw attention to:
  `{ hidden: i !== displayedPhoto % photoCount }`. I've added the `% photoCount` part for an edge case: if/when you switch from a vendor having, say 10 pictures, to one with, say 5 pictures, if the displayed photo index is above 5, no picture will be visible until the interval fn runs again. Adding `% photoCount` makes sure a picture of the new vendor is displayed. Alternatively, we could watch `vendor` and set `displayedPhoto` to `0` on `vendor` changed.
- speaking of swapping `vendor`, I also added a more robust way of handling the *"slider"*, making sure no interval is left running, in any scenario.

See it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-einstein-h8oxuc?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue). Notes:

- I had to mock the axios request with a promise returning an approximation of the actual call's response.
- I made a custom fader for the images, since you haven't shared that code

That's about it.